# Smooth customizeable jQuery transitions?

Tags: jquery, transition, customization, smoothing

I'm looking for recommendations for great smooth jQuery transitions for images/divs/elements. I need to be able to run at least 8 of these simultaneously on the same page and still have it smoother than a baby's bottom. I would also like to control duration, size and transition effects for each picture. Anything you guys can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I can offer the reminder that jQuery is entirely client side so smoother than a baby's bottom is always dependent on the user's hardware

Comment: the .animate family easing functions is the first step, the the Raphael plugin (or equivalent) shall allow you to reach this goal.

Comment: How can I use the .animate easing functions to mimic a slider?